# aws java sdk for ssm gives java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SIGNING_REGION

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lambda

Following code gives NoSuchFieldError when used in Lambda. The same works in a simple java program. Appreciate any help..

```
        AWSSimpleSystemsManagementAsync client = AWSSimpleSystemsManagementAsyncClientBuilder.defaultClient();

        PutParameterRequest putRequest = new PutParameterRequest();
        putRequest.setName("testKey");
        putRequest.setValue("testValue");
        client.putParameter(putRequest);
```

Digging into the source code shows error at AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java ->                request.addHandlerContext(HandlerContextKey.SIGNING_REGION, getSigningRegion());

Also tried with 
AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard();
AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.defaultClient();
WSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1").build();
returning the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you have don't have a mistmach of aws versions. you might be having the same issue I had, upgrading ssm aws version to 1.11.301 while other components had the 1.11.271 aws core version, causing the same exception. You should make sure versions are aligned